# Htaccess remove .php and redirect specific URL

Tags: .htaccess

My **htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule !^error - [R=404,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

I want to do this:

```
http://localhost:1993/test => load test.php but hide extension
http://localhost:1993/test.php => error 404 page
http://localhost:1993/test?lang=en (en, cs, fr etc) => http://localhost:1993/test
```

**I have this link that changes my language based on this [link](https://daveismyname.blog/how-to-create-a-language-changer-with-php)**

```
<a href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php') . '?lang=cs';?>"><?=$lang["lang-cs"];?></a>
```

Language switch works but clicking on the link will change the URL to 
    http://localhost:1993/test.php and shows 404 error.

I want redirect (just stop adding .php in URL after click this link)

http://localhost:1993/test?lang=en => http://localhost:1993/test